# Can't mount writable images in Disk Utility

Tags: macos, disk-utility, mojave, mount

I'm trying to add a file to an ISO then reburn it.  In Disk Utility, I mount the original ISO, choose "Create From ..." to create a new image file with "read/write" access and save it.  When I mount the new image file, it's read-only and I can't change it or add files.

What am I doing wrong?  Why can't I mount the image with write permissions?

Comment: Why not copy the files from the iso to a folder, add your new files, then reburn?

Comment: The ISO is bootable.  I'm not confident that it would still work when I'm done.  The benefit of the ISO is that it keeps the boot information.

Comment: You may have to use the `hdiutil` command to create the new iso file. Basically, I do not think you can accomplish your task using the Disk Utility application. Do you know how the current iso file is configured to boot?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make an ISO for unattended installs of Windows.

Comment: Windows? Why didn't you say? Are you doing a legacy eltorito boot or EFI boot? You can do this using macOS, but would it not be better to do this using Windows?

Comment: Man... I would LOVE to do this in Windows, but unfortunately we're a Mac company and only use Windows for a couple of very specific applications that we'll be hosting on a VM.

Comment: Exactly. Do this by running a Windows in a Virtual Machine hosted on a Mac running macOS. You can do this completely for free. This would make testing easier. You would not have to actually do a burn to test. However, I you still want to do this using only macOS and then burn, I can post something of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a physical or virtual FAT32 or ExFAT formatted drive. You could mount the ISO file and then copy all the files to this drive. I would recommend using the Terminal application to do the copy. Using the Finder application may result in the creation of `._*` files. Although these files can be removed by using `dot_clean`.

To create a legacy bootable ISO file, use the command given below.

```
hdiutil makehybrid -o windows10.iso /Volumes/ESD-USB -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 8 -eltorito-boot /Volumes/ESD-USB/boot/etfsboot.com
```

In this example, the name of the drive shown in the finder was `ESD-USB`. The `-boot-load-size` was set to 8 sectors, because the size of the `etfsboot.com` file was 4096 bytes and the sector size is 512 bytes. `( 8 * 512 = 4096 )`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify ISO files using Disk Utility, nor using diskutil on the commandline. This is not built in to those programs.